# Pass data from laravel to a component in blade view

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I created a PasswordFields.vue file.

```
<template>
<div>
    <el-form-item label="Mot de passe"
                prop="password"
                :error="this.registerForm.errors.get('password')"
                required
                :rules="[{ 'min': 6, message: 'Le mot de passe doit faire au moins 6 caractères', trigger: ['blur', 'change'] }]">
        <el-input type="password" name="password" id="password" v-model="this.registerForm.password">
        </el-input>
    </el-form-item>

    <!-- confirm password -->
    <el-form-item label="Confirmation du mot de passe"
                prop="password_confirmation"
                :error="this.registerForm.errors.get('password_confirmation')"
                required
                :rules="[{ 'min': 6, message: 'Le mot de passe doit faire au moins 6 caractères', trigger: ['blur', 'change'] }]">
        <el-input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" v-model="this.registerForm.password_confirmation">
        </el-input>
    </el-form-item>
</div>
</template>
```

Whenever I call my component in my Blade view, like this:

```
<password-fields></password-fields>
```

I have an error that says **the property or method method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render**.

I tried this, but it still does not work

`<password-fields registerForm="registerForm"></password-fields>`

Can you help me ? How to pass the value to my component? thank you very much

EDIT (the end of my component)

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
  var validatePass = (rule, value, callback) => {
    if (value === '') {
      callback(new Error('Please input the password'));
    } else {
      if (this.registerForm.password_confirmation !== '') {
        this.$refs.registerForm.validateField('password_confirmation');
      }
      callback();
    }
  };
  var validatePass2 = (rule, value, callback) => {
    if (value === '') {
      callback(new Error('Please input the password again'));
    } else if (value !== this.registerForm.password) {
      callback(new Error('Two inputs don\'t match!'));
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  };
  return {
    rulesPass: {
      pass: [
        { validator: validatePass, trigger: 'blur' }
      ],
      checkPass: [
        { validator: validatePass2, trigger: 'blur' }
      ]
    }
  }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `:registerForm="registerForm"` instead and use `props`

Comment: Could you show us `PasswordFields` component?

Comment: @imrealashu I I added the end of my component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. never use `this` in the template
2. declare `props` in component

Example Component:

```
<template>
<div>
    <el-form-item label="Mot de passe"
                prop="password"
                :error="registerForm.errors.get('password')"
                required
                :rules="[{ 'min': 6, message: 'Le mot de passe doit faire au moins 6 caractères', trigger: ['blur', 'change'] }]">
        <el-input type="password" name="password" id="password" v-model="registerForm.password">
        </el-input>
    </el-form-item>

    <!-- confirm password -->
    <el-form-item label="Confirmation du mot de passe"
                prop="password_confirmation"
                :error="registerForm.errors.get('password_confirmation')"
                required
                :rules="[{ 'min': 6, message: 'Le mot de passe doit faire au moins 6 caractères', trigger: ['blur', 'change'] }]">
        <el-input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" v-model="registerForm.password_confirmation">
        </el-input>
    </el-form-item>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
  var validatePass = (rule, value, callback) => {
    if (value === '') {
      callback(new Error('Please input the password'));
    } else {
      if (this.registerForm.password_confirmation !== '') {
        this.$refs.registerForm.validateField('password_confirmation');
      }
      callback();
    }
  };
  var validatePass2 = (rule, value, callback) => {
    if (value === '') {
      callback(new Error('Please input the password again'));
    } else if (value !== this.registerForm.password) {
      callback(new Error('Two inputs don\'t match!'));
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  };
  return {
    rulesPass: {
      pass: [
        { validator: validatePass, trigger: 'blur' }
      ],
      checkPass: [
        { validator: validatePass2, trigger: 'blur' }
      ]
    }
  }
    }
}
  props: ['registerForm'],
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian Scholle. I tried your solution. I do not have the mistake I mentioned, but now he's telling me that `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined"`. For example, when I try to access `registerForm.errors`

Comment: Finally, I used v-bind:register-form (as I was using CamelCase and HTML does not recognize it, I had to put dashes instead). Now, with props, all work fine!